# Fetch timeout when port-forwarding from docker container

Tags: javascript, docker, browser, network-programming, portforwarding

I'm working on simple project consisting of two docker containers in docker network (bridge). The issue it that I'm getting timeout from backend when calling it from host (via port-forward to frontend)

Setup:

`docker network create --driver bridge my-network`

1. Java Spring backend providing random quotes from database under `/randomQuote` endpoint

`docker run -it --rm --name backend --network my-network backend:1.0`

2. Javascript frontend for displaying the received quote

`docker run -it --rm --name frontend --network my-network -p 8081:8081 frontend:1.0`

Frontend code for requesting the data (called on button click):

```
const requestQuote = async() => {
    let response = await fetch(apiUrl + getRandomQuoteEndpoint)
    if(handleErrors(response)){
        quote = await response.json()
        displayQuote()
    }
}
```

I tried various versions for `apiUrl` like:

```
http://backend:8080
http://172.18.0.2:8080
backend:8080
172.18.0.2:8080
```

Backend interface:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public interface QuotesRestController {

    @CrossOrigin()
    @GetMapping("/randomQuote")
    public ResponseEntity<Quote> getRandomQuote();
}
```

On host `http://localhost:8081/` is displaying `frontend` content properly but when requesting the quote I'm receiving `GET http://172.18.0.2:8080/randomQuote net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

`curl` from frontend is returning the quotes correctly, so issue is only when I'm port-forwarding and trying to display on host.

I suspect that this is because the call to backend:8080/randomQuote is made from my host's browser which is not in docker network so it's not able to reach backend.

Is it an issue with my configuration/code? Or I should use different approach?